# How to drop column with laravel migration on sqlite?

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I want to write test for my application, but i getting error when run the migration;

[image: There is no column with name]

My Migration file

```
Schema::table('bill_payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('attachment');
    // $table->getColumns(); return empty array
    // $table->dropColumn(['attachment']); I tried this
});

dd(Schema::hasColumn('bill_payments', 'attachment')); // Return false

// and this is not working because return false.

if(Schema::hasColumn('bill_payments', 'attachment'))
{
    Schema::table('bill_payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('attachment');
    });
}
```

Also i add doctrine/dbal 2.5.13

i running tests using mysql, but slowly.

**[Solved]**

Wow! i using prefix for tables. i deleted this  and now it's work.

Comment: Do you have this column? Where do you create it?

Comment: Can you confirm that column really exists? there is nothing wrong

Comment: Yes, it is creating before run this, and i see this column when i checked db.

Comment: Ok. The easiest way is to delete everything inside your testing database .sqlite file and run again.

Comment: I tried, also delete sqlite file and create it again but doesn't work.

Comment: with newer versions of laravel (9.44+) you don't need doctrine/dbal anymore

Answer (score 4):

One thing you need to know about migrations is that they run untill they crash or succeed, following your example:

```
Schema::table('bill_payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('attachment');
});
//It will drop the column and stop here. When you run the migration again, it will output your error because the column no longer exists.
dd(Schema::hasColumn('bill_payments', 'attachment')); // Return false
```

What you should have in your migration code is having the reverse operations in the Down() method. Meaning you run the migration, it applies the Up() and when you rollback, it reverts correctly. That error is really what it means, it means that when it reaches an operation relating table `bill_payments` and column `attachment`, it recognizes that `attachment` doesn't exist.

Edit:

There is something related to SQlite in the documentation:

["Dropping or modifying multiple columns within a single migration while using a SQLite database is not supported."](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#dropping-columns)

Comment: I actually added the dd and others lines for debugging. Originally i have up and down methods, and i deleting column in "up" method, creating column in "down" method.

Comment: i read this, but i try drop only one column not multiple. what am I missing?

Comment: With SQLite 3.35.0+ column drops and renames are implemented in sqlite